# Shopify serverside API for getting cart content -

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopifysharp

In Shopify, you can use the Storefront Ajax API to get the "checkout" for a user, aka. the cart.

Is there something similar for getting the cart serverside?

As far as I can tell from reading the documentation, you can only access "checkouts" once the user has entered their address etc - not while they are still putting stuff in the basket...

Comment: No, there's no standard API endpoint to get that info server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vladimir said in a comment - there is no way to get cart content via a serverside API.